# Reverse geocoding blocked

Tags: javascript, https, here-api, reverse-geocoding

Reverse geocoding is blocked by Chrome and Firefox browsers. Probably because of the request url is http:// instead of https://

Url used by the Here JavaScript files:
http://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json

I am using the following JavaScript libraries from Here.
- mapsjs-core.js
- mapsjs-service.js

The code is located in an AWS S3 bucket in combination with Cloudfront https://.

What should I do to avoid the code reverse geocoding from being blocked?

Comment: `https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json` seems to work. And you are probably looking for this: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-service-platform.html#h-service-platform__setusehttps

Comment: Thanks @SergiuParaschiv! Adding 'useHTTPS': true to the platform variable worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get success response by sending below request-

```
https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.{format}
```

Parameter list can be added from here

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/resource-reverse-geocode.html